Make mint authority the program itself
Is there any possibility to make the program be the mint authority for a mint.
I thought about making:
mint authority -> PDA derived from programid
That would mean that to mint, only the program signing in behalf of the PDA would be able.
Is this a workaround?

This is possible, but I'd advise against it.
You'd need to have your program keypair sign for ix's and if it gets compromised, both your program and tokens are jeopardized.
The PDA strategy you highlighted is a better and safer alternative.
